# How to link to same page and add a GET parameter? Additive GET parameters?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a page with a table and pagination.

I can flick through the pages with

```
<a href="?page={{ myobj.next_page_number }}">
<a href="?page={{ myobj.previous_page_number }}">
```

Now I want to add ordering to the tables.

```
<th><a href="?sort=date&order=asc">Date</a></th>
```

In the given example, I lose either the pagination or the ordering upon clicking one of the hyperlinks. I need to find a way to make the GET parameters additive. So when I am on page 2, the latter should show

```
<th><a href="?page=2&sort=date&order=asc">Date</a></th>
```

I hope there is a built-in solution for that. I am on Django 1.10, but wouldn't mind upgrading to 1.11 if necessary.

Comment: Take GET parameters in your view. Pass them to template. Add them together. `?page={{ page }}&sort={{ sort }}&order={{ order }}`

Comment: In addition of @AndreyShipilov, take a look at the `QUERY_STRING`  variables that you would have available in your template https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to that is cath in the urls.py the param of the page and use it in the Paginator object.

```
p = Paginator(your queryset, N°of record per page)
```

in the P variable will find the pages of the queryset.
Assign the value to anoter variable

```
page1 = p.page(1)
```

and in the template use:

```
page1.object_list
```

if you desire you can use https://datatables.net/
for manage all the pages and the order.
for big data see https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to generate the string that you want to append on all links in your view first, and then add them to the links.

Here is an example of how you can use `urlencode` ([Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode)) to generate a string of GET parameters.

```
from urllib import urlencode, quote
from collections import OrderedDict

page_value = 2
sort_value = "date"
order_value = "asc"
query_string = urlencode(OrderedDict(page=page_value, sort=sort_value, order=order_value))

# outputs page=2&sort=date&order=asc
```